# Problem with sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, 17.04

when I run `sudo apt-get update` command, I got these errors:

```
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is no longer supported, you should upgrade your system to 17.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

Zesty is already EOL as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
My suggestion would be to upgrade to latest supported version of Ubuntu

Also you might take a look here:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-January/000227.html